RangeError: encoding overruns Uint8Array
I am getting this error when combining two sets of swap instructions into one, can anyone elaborate on what causes it? Thanks

RangeError: encoding overruns Uint8Array


What on-chain program do you refer to here? I mean what program is the owner of the Swap instruction that you call?

Perhaps you are exceeding the transaction size limit which is 1232 bytes for the data
